# Layout & Navigation using Horizontal Tabs (tabbed window) vs Vertical Tabs (sections)

Tags: layout, navigation, salesforce, dynamics-crm-2011

For our new project, we are currently looking for latest "standard" layout. It is a business webapp which includes lot of master-detail screens/forms.

In our previous projects, we have extensively used horizontal tabs like **[JQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)**.

I remember old version (5) of Dynamics CRM also utilised similar approach but in there latest 2011 version, they have replaced layout to include vertical tabs like **[this](http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/042011_1256_DynamicsCRM2.png)**.

I also noticed SalesForce has also related information on vertical "tab" which is essentially multiple sections on long long page. I could not find much discussion about this sort of decision? Note that MS/SF has separate layouts for mobile & surely they are not expecting businesses to use tablets.

Is everyone moving towards vertical layout when screens are becoming wider? Is there any  reason for this shift?

**Edit:**
This is what I am talking about, the question is why?

1. [Tab Performance - CRM 4.0 vs CRM 2011](http://mscrmdev.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/tab-performance-crm-40-vs-crm-2011.html)
2. [No More Tabbing – Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2011/01/11/No_More_Tabbing_%E2%80%93_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Microsoft is changing again the CRM 2011 interface, starts from Polaris release they introduced new forms, take a look at this article and the included slides:

http://niiranen.eu/crm/2013/01/whats-new-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-polaris-release-slides/

This release brings cross-browser compatibility including Safari on iPad, so as you can see Microsoft (and SalesForce and other companies too) adapt their products trying to provide the best UI for their customers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & link. The new interface (actually new forms) is adding new panels which helps to present more data but haven't gone back to horizontal tabs. 

So does your answer mean shift is towards the effective use of real-estate & horizontal tabs are still a good option?